# How do i add custom Json to an elastic4s search

Tags: elastic4s

Is there any way for elastic4s to allow me to build this search request:

```
 {
  "size" : 100,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : {
          "disabled" : false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "gas-filter" : {
      "name" : "SearchResultCypherFilter",
      "query" : "MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS*]->(d{referenceId:'522d8b956819338605a53948c5dcef1a'}) RETURN distinct a.referenceId as guid",
      "exclude" : true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

elastic4s version 2.3.1 and greater allows you to add a extra source Json

```
search in "maalka" bool matchAllQuery limit 10 extraSource Json.stringify(Json.obj(
  "gas-filter" -> Json.obj(
      "name" -> "SearchResultCypherFilter",
      "query" -> "MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS*]->(d{referenceId:'522d8b956819338605a53948c5dcef1a'}) RETURN distinct a.referenceId as guid",
      "exclude" -> true)
))
```